# Is there a specific command in Powershell for moving a file?

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to move a file using Microsoft Powershell,
I've looked on the Microsoft website and didn't understand the instructions.
Here is the directory contents as shown by `Get-ChildItem`:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\Username\lpthw


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/19/2020   6:38 PM                useful
-a----         5/9/2020   2:08 PM            263 drill5.py
```

Q: I would like to know how I can move the file `drill5.py` to the directory `useful`.

Comment: Why not search [powershell move file](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+move+file&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL793IL793&oq=powershell+move+file&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4695j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - the first result points the the documentation by Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7

```
Move-Item -Path .\drill5.py -Destination .\useful\

# Another way. mv is an alias for Move-Item
mv .\drill5.py .\useful\
```

Comment: I received an error while doing the command:
``mv drill5.py useful```
 mv drill.py useful
mv : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Username\lpthw\drill.py' because it does not exist.

Comment: what error? ` Move-Item -Path .\drill5.py -Destination .\useful\ `

Comment: that error is saying that the file does not exist: C:\Users\Username\lpthw\drill.py  Is the file there?

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Username\lpthw\drill.py:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: @JonyHadary Your error says `drill.py`, not `drill5.py` - did you forget to type the `5`?

Comment: Yes it is Carlos, but i tried this command and it worked. 


Move-Item -Path drill5.py -Destination useful

Comment: thank you Mathias for your comment. But yet, when i use the command mv, it changes the name of the file, but it doesn't move from one place to other

Comment: @JonyHadary is `drill5.py` the real file name? Or does the real file name perhaps contain `[5]` (square brackets)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it is the real file name. Maybe there is another way to move files. Because when I use the mv command, it changes the name of the file, but doesnt move it.

Comment: you are probably missing a `\ ` at the end of useful... `Move-Item -Path .\drill5.py -Destination .\useful\ `

Comment: It is weird, but i tried your advices and paid attention to the details, but what happened in the end is just changing the names from the older name drill5.py to lpthw ( this is the name of the directory i want to send). the file stays in the directory.